# Reading from external text file in python

Tags: python, file

```
v = open('text.txt')
g = v.read()
print(len(g))
```

Output:

```
10
```

The problem is that text.txt only contains the word  "hello" inside it.The output should be 5 since the word "hello" has only 5 characters

Comment: There's some whitespace in there is my guess!

Comment: add `print(g)` line

Answer (score 2):

Encoding may change the size of the file by adding non-printable characters.

I assume you used Windows Notepad to create your file, because of the '.txt' extension. Notepad can write your file in 'UTF-8 with BOM' which adds 3 bytes to the beginning of your file. If you added new line to the file, this adds 1 byte 'LF' (\n)<sup>1</sup>, so I think you have one more new line or a whitespace in the file for you to reach 10 bytes in length.

<sup>1</sup>On Windows, it is 'CRLF' (\r\n) in the file, but Python reads new lines as 'LF' for cross compatibility regardless the OS, if you read the file in byte mode, you will get the CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) to view the printable version of the string. It may give insight as to why the length is different than expected.

```
print(repr(g))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly more in the file than just the string "hello". Maybe you wrote it in Windows Notepad like another user suggested, or maybe there is just trailing whitespace that you forgot to delete.

When I run this program, I get the output `6`, which is the length of the string plus the `EOF` or a newline or something. In any case, it is better practice to read files this way in python:

```
with open(text.txt) as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        # do something
```

There will be a trailing newline at the end of each line that you can remove with the `replace()` function